# How make fixed webkit-mask for div?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, webkit

Suppose we have two blocks div superposed, the only difference between them is that in the lower block to the content div applied effect assume a black-white filter `-webkit-filter: grayscale (100%);`

If the div-block p2 reduced in size by height and synchronize scrolling then we will achieve the transition effect of color content in black-white.

However, site that I try to write is designed for mobile devices and iOS have problem with get dynamic position scrolling.
As alternatively can use iscroll, but very slows work...

So idea came to cut div-block id="p2" using webkit-mask mask and to fix webkitmask relative to page. 
For more detail in the gif-animation:
http://outsins.com/mask.gif

```
<div id="scroll" style="-webkit-overflow-crolling:touch;left:200px;width:500px;height:500px;">

<div id="p1" style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:1000px;z-index:1;-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);">
some text
</div>

<div id="p2" style="position:absolute;width:500px;height:1000px;z-index:2; color: blue;-webkit-mask:url(heartmask.png) no-repeat center center;-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;">
some text
</div>

</div>
```

I put two superimposed block in common container and added -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch. 
Now while scrolling two div-block  (p1 and p2) are move simultaneously.
On the top layer (id: p2), I added webkitmask `-webkit-mask: url (heartmask.png)` and make it fixed: `-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;`
Thus, the content should be clipped by the mask which supposedly should not move.

But `-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;` does not work, and the mask is moved together with the whole page
http://outsins.com/mask2.gif

I did not find any example with `-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;`

And I think that I am wrong somewhere

Where is my mistake? How can I fix this?

Sorry for bad english...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;` is not supported by the majority of browsers. It is supported only by Chome and Safari. (see the [browser compatibility in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-attachment)).

Try to use `position:fixed` for `div#p2`:

```
<div id="p2" style="position:fixed;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help
position:fixed - not suitable in this case, and I'm testing on Safari 4.0 where there is supported, but -webkit-mask-attachment: fixed doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try use svg mask. 
See here for more detail: http://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

```
<img class="clip-svg" src="harry.jpg" alt="Harry Potter">

<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="40" />
      <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

.clip-svg {
  clip-path: url(#myClip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid background, you can simply add the mask to the p1 div that is fixed above and p2 content should appear to be affected beneath giving the impression that the mask is fixed and applied to p2. This website: https://ajy.co/web/fade-to-background-image-in-css/ discusses fading to a duplicate of the background image. I think I know what you're looking for because I am looking for the same thing. Unfortunately my design has many layers of transparency so simply applying a duplicate image and fading it is not an option for me. Hope this helped.

I too have not been able to find an alternative to the broken recommendation for

-webkit-mask-attachment: fixed;